# When using the Google Picker, what does the .setDocument(document) do/used for?

Tags: google-picker

Context: The feature I am working on is exporting user data into a Google Document that appears exactly as the PDF version we export but allows for easier editing. Because this file has a lot of complex tables I created a template document, that is public to *everyone* with viewer access via link, that contains the all the potential tables needed with formatting/styling that are then programmatically adjusted or outright deleted as needed. This currently works by copying the file to the users drive and then taking the file id from the response to use the Docs API to fill it with data using the `.../auth/drive` scope.

I have been developing an alternative flow for our app so we can avoid using the permissive, restricted scope `.../auth.drive` and instead uses the `.../auth/drive.file` and `.../auth/drive.metadata` scopes and the Google Picker. This tries the initial flow and then, if the app recieves a 403 "user has not granted app APP_NUMBER_HERE access to file _FILE_ID_HERE" error, their is a dialog that describes the user needs to follow a link to view the file (and this allows them to access it from their drive) and then if they follow the link pops the Google Picker and requests they select *that* file.

Everything works decently well but the documentation mentions a function `.setDocument(document)` for the `google.picker.PickerBuilder()` that doesn't have much documentation or examples (link to picker builder section in documentation: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#picker-builder). It sounds like it could allow me to be set the specific for them to choose however I cannot get it working or know how to use it correctly.

I have tried to test it when building the picker object like:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS)
    .setTitle("Please pick the <fileName> file")
    // .setDocument(document) // this breaks the entire picker, creating a undefined object
    .setAppId(appID)
    .setOAuthToken(token)
    .setDeveloperKey(devKey)
    .setCallback(filePickerCallback)
    .build();
  picker.setVisible(true);
```

Note for the "document" I have tried using the document ID, and a URL of the document as well, but it breaks the picker every time.

Does anyone know what the `setDocument` function is for? Or how to use it correctly?

Comment: This looks to be related to the first comment on a post at https://stackoverflow.com/q/36022256/15384825 that talks about the description of the setDocument(document) method on PickerBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Since gapi is a closed-source product, the official and correct answer can be achieved only by asking Google.

One thing I know is, [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) has type definitions for the Google Picker API, which you can use by:

```
npm i -D @types/google.picker
```

According to [this definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4d36ebc9253e57b2f3117eea9af3cc18adc2a6ab/types/google.picker/index.d.ts#L54), `setDocument` takes an argument of type `Document` i.e. `document` as in `document.write`.
This suggests this function is not something you are looking for.